# Sending String Text/Plain Value via Post Request

Tags: java, angular, rest, httpclient

I am attempting what seems to me should be a relatively simple task.
I want to send a string (stored here as "note") as the body of a Post request. The error I am currently running into is a 415 (mediatype mismatch), although it looked to me as if I was matching the mediatypes (using text/plain).

Relevant imports:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

Here is the Angular9 service sending the request:

```
addNote(note: string, transId) {
    return this.http.post(Constants.API.ACCUMSUI_APP + '/inboundHeader/addnote/' + transId, note, 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'})}
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Here is (some of) the Rest controller taking in the request:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/addnote/{aithSeqId}", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addNote(
            @PathVariable Long aithSeqId,
            @RequestBody String noteText
           )
```

I'm thinking I'm just missing something simple. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just an idea - have you tried a header of just 'ContentType': 'text/plain', without the `charset=UTF-8`? Alternatively, you could set `consumes` to include the charset explicitly by supplying the full string? The handling of charset with a specified MediaType is not clear from the documentation.

Comment: Hi Myk, thank you for the reply. I just tried your suggestion and it still produces the same 415 error, unfortunately. I have also tried changing the request headers so that they are simply `text/plain`, and this produces the same result as well.